# which one is better create-react-native-app or react-native-cli

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[i ran the commands on windows machine by creating 2 folders. Im not sure what happens if i install in single folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omeYA.png)

I recently started working on react native.Then  i noticed there are two commands listed to build react native apps.

So i decided to test them which one is better.So i ran both of them and found CRNA is better in terms of speed.

But i find more files installed in react-cli folder than in react-app.
will that make my work harder.

please suggest me which one is better for both android and ios developement.If i can find out which one to work with i will try this on mac.I havent done in mac because i have to run a VM which makes my machine slow.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In terms of performance**

There's no difference between the two.

**Main Difference**

Both allow you to use all of the [components and APIs in react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis.html). but `create-react-native-app` allows you to:

1. Use JavaScript APIs provided by [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/index.html), for example, the `MapView`
2. Run your app on an IOS device if you do not have a MAC but have an iPhone, but you need to download the Expo app on App Store
3. Forget about XCode and Android Studio because it builds your app for you

And `react-native init XXX` command will also create a react native project, which allows you to use modules that require to be linked via command `react-native link XXX`. For example, `react-native-fetch-blob`. If you want to use this module, but your app was created using `create-react-native-app`, unfortunately you can't, unless you 'eject', in which case, you won't be able to use those Expo APIs. [Read more here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/create-react-native-app.html)

If you're very new to react native, I would recommend CRNA. But as you add more features to your app, Expo's APIs can no longer meet your requirement, I suggest that eventually, you should abandon it

Comment: Thank you. I'll now stick on to CRNA rather than cli.